# Find all $c$ for which a set of vectors is linearly independent set of vectors in $R^3$

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

Find all $c$ that belongs to $R$ for which $S = \{ (c^2,0,1), (0,c,0), (1,2,1) \}$ is a linearly independent set of vectors in $R^3$.

I tried to solve this problem by setting the determinant of these vectors equal to $0$, and then solve it, but I couldn't.

the det is $c^2$ ((c)-0)-0(0-2)+1(0-c)
by simplifying it is $c^3$+c

Comment: You say you tried to set up a determinant. How far did you get? What stopped you from getting an answer?

Comment: I stopped at c^3+c

Comment: Could you be a bit more detailed? Please, edit your question post to tell us exactly how far you got, how you got there, and why you stopped where you stopped.

Comment: @Arthur I edited it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost at the goal!

First things first, you have a small error. Note that $1(0-c) = -c$, so the determinant becomes $c^3-c$.

$c^3-c = 0$ is actually one of the easier cubic equations to solve. Note that we can factor
$$
c^3 - c = c(c^2-1) = c(c-1)(c+1)
$$
If we want this to be $0$, then one of the three factors has to be $0$. So we get the three solutions $c = 0$ (which is actually obvious just looking at the vectors), $c = 1$ and $c = -1$ (which, in retrospect, are obvious as they make it easy to write the third vector as a linear combination of the first two). The determinant also makes it clear that there can be no other solutions (which is *not* immediately obvious just from looking at the vectors).

So the three vectors are linearly dependent iff $c$ is either $0$ or $\pm 1$, and thus any other value will make the vectors linearly independent.